# logstash grok build in pattern for java.util.logging LOGLEVEL

Tags: logging, logstash-grok

I currently configure **logstash** and I am desperately searching for a

**grok** buildin **pattern** for the LOGLEVEL of java.util.logging

```
%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}
```

will not work, because it does not match `FINE`, `FINEST`,

EDIT:
I thought the problem is, that the [grok build-in](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns) pattern LOGLEVEL only contains LOG4J but not JUL levels, but this is not the case.

I am trying with [Crok Constructor](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match)

```
^%{IPORHOST:clientip}
```

matches

```
10.121.123.104 - - [01/Nov/2012:21:01:17 +0100] "GET /cpc/auth.do?loginsetup=true&targetPage=%2Fcpc%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 466
```

but

```
^%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}
```

does not match

```
2016-12-28 00:15:04,732 WARN 
[org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation::processInvocation] (default task-315) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component
```

Comment: Did you try editing your `LOGLEVEL` in your `patterns`?

Comment: `LOGLEVEL` is a grok built-in pattern

Comment: [link](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns)

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you've shown:

```
^%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}
```

says "look at the beginning of the line to match the LOGLEVEL pattern".

The input you've shown starts with a datetime, not a log level.